# Clicking radio button in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

Is there any trick to click radio button with code ?
I've already tried **radioButton.setChecked(true)** and **.setSelected(true)**.
But that's not I want. That two methods can't trigger the **event** of the button.
I wrote an onclick listener for each radio button that makes an EditText appears under the clicked button. 
So, I need a method like radioButton.click() if possible. 
Thanks..

Comment: Try to use performClick().

Comment: Add android:onClick in the xml and create the function of that click in the class to handle its click events , i think this is what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setChecked` and `setSelected` only change the state of the button. You could use `performClick()` to obtain a simulated click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your RadioButtons inside a RadioGroup and use RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener. Something Like this.

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
       {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
           {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(radiobutton1.isChecked())
              {
                   // do something
              }
            else if(radiobutton2.isChecked())
              {
                // do something

              }
         }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it might works. I'll try it later.

Comment: Okay.. glad to help you.. gud nyt @CristyYG

Answer (score 0):

Just Put your radio buttons in a group and implement a on change listener on it like this.

```
myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
       {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedButton) 
           {
            switch(checkedBUtton){
                  case 1:
                      // Your code to display edittext
                  break;
                  case 1:
                      // Your code to display edittext
                  break;
                  ///////////////////
              }
         }
    });
```